# -f option for rmdir

Tags: rm, options

#### Short version:

I am searching for a way to get the behaviour of the `-f` flag in `rm` when using `rmdir`.

#### Long version:

I am running a parallel process where every command must clean up its working directory after completion. Commands may operate in the same working directory, so `rmdir -p --ignore-fail-on-non-empty` works perfectly to prevent a worker removing a directory that is still in use by another worker. The only problem seems to arise when the last two workers based in the same directory finish simultaneously-- then one of the workers is beaten to the punch and `rmdir` returns the error "No such file or directory".

Is there a way to make `rmdir` ignore this non-issue, as `rm` does with `-f`?

(`rm` does have the `-d` option which may be a different solution, but I can't see any way to get the `-p --ignore-fail-on-non-empty` type behaviour with `rm`. In any case, `-d` is not universal to all versions of `rm` so it is better to avoid that approach.)

Comment: What errors from `rmdir` do you want to see/handle? Maybe you can afford to ignore all of them. Or maybe it's better to run a separate process just to remove stale directories after all the parallel jobs finish, without collisions, instead of cleaning on the fly and getting in each other's way. It's up to you what is acceptable.

Comment: `rm` does not have a `-d` option.

Comment: @schily, the GNU and *BSD versions do. Anyway, they did say it's not universal.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I can definitely ignore them, but they clog up log files (over nearly 1 million commands, it happens regularly enough). I have to remove the directories on the fly unfortunately due to file count restrictions on the HPC I am using. It just seems like `rmdir` should have the `-f` option if `rm` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the directory exists first:

```
[ -d "$tmpdir" ] && rmdir -p --ignore-fail-on-non-empty "$tmpdir"
```

This could still produce errors if two jobs start to remove the directory at exactly the same time (a [TOCTOU vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use): both test and see the directory, then both try to remove it), but that's probably not too likely.

Or you could just ignore every error `rmdir` might produce:

```
rmdir -p --ignore-fail-on-non-empty "$tmpdir" 2>/dev/null || true
```

Or, create a program of your own to remove the directory but to ignore the "File does not exist" error only. E.g. with Perl:

```
perl -le 'if (not rmdir($ARGV[0]) and not $!{ENOENT}) { 
       warn "rmdir: $!\n"; exit 1; }' "$tmpdir"
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I think the first option still has the potential to error. I suppose ignoring all errors is best, but maybe risky if something else goes wrong. But then -f probably causes a similar risk.